# Show that if A is invertible, then $Au_1,Au_2,\ldots, Au_k$ are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

There is an added condition of

Suppose $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_k$ are linearly independent.
Show that if A is invertible, then $Au_1,Au_2,\ldots,Au_k$ are linearly independent.

> my solution
>
> since $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_k$ are linearly independent, then $c_1 u_1+c_2 u_2+\cdots+c_k u_k=0$ implies $c_1,\ldots$ are all zero.
>
> by multiplying A on both sides, we have $c_1 A  u_1+c_2 A u_2+\cdots =c_k A u_k=0$ since all those c can only be 0, therefore $Au_1,Au_2,\ldots,Au_k$ are linearly independent.

Notice how i didnt use the supposition if A is invertive and still get the answer. I am wondering if my answer is right or wrong...

Comment: You have to start with the second equation. Is there some way back to the first, so that you can apply lin.ind. of the $u_i$?

Comment: I get what you mean, but if i could get the answer without using the suposition, isn tthat better? That is, so i have shown that no matter if a is invertible or not, the answer will always be linearly independent

Comment: @SingaporeanDude.: But that result is clearly false (take $A=0$ for example), so your reasoning must be flawed.

Comment: Im still unsure how is it flawed :(

Comment: Just because the coefficients have to be $0$ for the $\mathbf{u_i}$ to sum to $\mathbf{0}$ doesn't mean the same holds for $A\mathbf{u_i}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Assume by negation they are linear dependent and write
a non-trivial linear combination that sums to zero.

Now this is the step where if the $A$ weren't there then you had
a non-trivial linear combination of the $u_{i}$'s that sums to zero,
can you get rid of the $A$ ? remember that $A$ is invertible means
there exist $A^{-1}$

**ADDED**: Your "proof" is incorrect. What you did is take something of the form $0+...+0=0$ and multiplied it by $A$ (each $c_i$ is zero so basicly you summed zeros).

You **started out** with all the coefficients as zero (before multiplying by $A$), this does not show how **any** linear combination is zero.

To see this more clearly say I give you all the coefficient as $1$, that is : 
$Au_{1}+...+Au_{k}$ and I claim that $Au_{1}+...+Au_{k}=0$ can you
trace from your proof that this can not happen ?

Clearly it is wrong for take $A=0$ , then it is clear that $\{Au_{i}\}_{i=1}^{i=k}$
is linear dependent since all the vectors are $0$. The assumption
about $A$ is important

Comment: Thanks that makes things extremely clear!!

Comment: @SingaporeanDude. - I'm very glad it helps! :)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you haven’t paid enough attention to just what it is that you’re trying to prove. You want to show that the vectors $Au_1,\dots,Au_k$ are linearly independent. Write down exactly what this means: you want to show that **if** some linear combination $c_1Au_1+\ldots+c_kAu_k=0$, **then** $c_1=\ldots=c_k=0$. The most straightforward approach to proving an **if-then** statement is to assume the hypothesis and work your way to the conclusion. It isn’t always the best approach, or even a feasible approach, but it’s the most straightforward and therefore worth a look.

Assume, then, that $c_1Au_1+\ldots+c_kAu_k=0$. How can you reasonably hope to show that $c_1=\ldots=c_k=0$? One way would be somehow to find linearly independent vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k$ such that $c_1v_1+\ldots+c_kv_k=0$; then you could use the linear independence of the $v_i$ to conclude that $c_1=\ldots=c_k=0$. But where might these $v_i$ come from? Well, we know that $u_1,\dots,u_k$ are linearly independent, and they’re the only vectors about which we’ve been given any information, so perhaps we should try to show that $c_1u_1+\ldots+c_ku_k=0$. Is there any way to deduce that from the hypothesis that $c_1Au_1+\ldots+c_kAu_k=0$? **Here** is where you’ll use the information that $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $c_1Au_1+\ldots+c_kAu_k=0$. Then $A(c_1u_1+\ldots+c_ku_k)=0$. Since $A$ is invertible, we have $c_1u_1+\ldots+c_ku_k=0$. Since $u_1,\ldots,u_k$ are linearly independent, we have $c_1=\ldots=c_k=0$. Hence $Au_1,\ldots,Au_k$ are linearly independent.